# C9 IDE - Conda command not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, c9.io

I am trying to install conda on [c9-ide](https://c9.io/). My c9 terminal is running on `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`.

I did the following:

```
> wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
> sudo bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I basically clicked enter and yes throughout the installation.

My install location is: `/home/ubuntu/miniconda3`

I tried to close and reopen the terminal, but I still get:

```
> conda
bash: conda: command not found
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `conda` function to your shell by adding the following to your `.bashrc` file:

```
source /path/to/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate base
```

This procedure is detailed in the release notes for Conda 4.4: https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20

---

For conda versions older than 4.4, you need to add the conda binary to your `PATH` with the following in your `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=/path/to/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```